# What functions other than spore dispersal does a fruiting body serve in a mycelial network?

Tags: mycology, biological-networks

*I'm not exactly sure if this is the appropriate forum to ask this, so apologies in advance.*

My question is both technical and general: what are the less obvious functions that the individual mushroom might serve in a network of mycelia. My knowledge of biology is pretty limited but I know that, for example, some mushrooms absorb radiation with some effects on the underlying network or that the network might generally shift itself underground overtime based on the signals that the individual fruiting bodies "gather" over their above-ground lifespan on.. whatever, humidity, predators, other conditions of relevance.

This is not to mystify it too much, but i'm really interested in the biological dynamic where a "node in the network" contributes something to the decentralized network, this probably sounds familiar, fungi are just the most obvious example. I was wondering what would be the term for this to begin with if there is one and if somebody could point me to some work on it at any level of resolution: from ecology to genetics or mathematics.

Thank you very much.

Comment: A cheeky answer would be that for poisonous mushrooms, the fruiting body provides vomit, faeces and corpses for nutrients.